# How to update parent state After the child updates an object?

Tags: reactjs

I send the information to the utils component successfully in order to update the web service but can not update the state held by the parent

```
 return <User
 id = {item.id}
 name = {item.name}
 email = {item.email}
 street = {item.address.street}
 city = {item.address.city}
 zipcode = {item.address.zipcode}
 isCompletedTodos = {isCompletedTodos}
 unCompletedTodos = {unCompletedTodos}
 filterUsers={filteredUsers} 
 callbackUpdate={ data => utils.updateUser(data.id,data)}

 callbackDelete = { data => utils.deleteUser(data.id), data => this.setState(data)}
 />
}
```

Comment: You might want to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before asking.

Answer (score 0):

To do that you can:

1. Simple solution: pass callback from the parent element and call it on data change
2. More complex solution: Implement FLUX in your application (Redux or Mobx). So, your component will trigger the change in the store and both components will be updated afterward.

Answer (score 0):

You would do better to hold that callback in your parent, and pass it in as a prop.

Parent:

```
const callbackUpdate = (id, data) => {
  util.doStuff(data);
  setState(data);
};
// the same for delete

<UserWrapper ...props callback={callback}/>
```

Your component takes callback from props, just like everything else:

```
const UserWrapper = props => <User id={item.id} ...props callbackUpdate={data => props.callbackUpdate(item.id, data)} />;
```

Now your component (the one apparently wrapping `<User>`) doesn't need to know whether to update state first, or go to backend first, or whatever. It just calls whatever it is passed. And your parent can decide on eager or lazy updates of state, on error handling, everything.

You can further improve on that. Create those update functions in a hook:

```
const useUsersApi = () {
  // your lil bit of state for the parent:
  const [something, setSomething] = useState();

  const updateUser = (id, data) => {
    return axios.put(`/url/${id}`, data)
        .then((response) => {
           setSomething(response);
           return response;
         });
  }
    const deleteUser = (id, data) => {
    return axios.put(`/url/${id}`, data)
        .then((response) => {
           setSomething(null);
           return response;
         });;
  }
  return {
     something, 
     updateUser,
     deleteUser
  }
}
```

Now your parent can use this instead of useState directly:

```
const Parent = () => {
   const { something, updateUser, deleteUser } = useUsersApi();
   const item = whatever();
  return <UserWrapper item={item} updateUser={updateUser} deleteUser={deleteUser}/>
}
```

And your component from the post is then:

```
const UserWrapper = ({item, updateUser, deleteUser}) => {
  return <User id={item.id} ....
              callbackUpdate={data => updateUser(item.id, data}
              callbackDelete={data => deleteUser(item.id, data} />
```